# Перемещение персонажа в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать перемещение персонажа в 2D игре на unity?

Накидал на сцену кнопки вперед и назад и добавил в ним компоненты Event Trigger с событиями Pointer Down и Pointer Up

С урока https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZdCKgp-xd4 пытался взяв информацию реализовать движение вперед и назад, но не получается

```
public void BackButtonDown() {
    speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
    sprite.flipX = true;
}

public void ForwardButtonDown() {
    speedX = horizontalSpeed;
    sprite.flipX = false;
}

public void BackOrForwardButtonUp() {
    speedX = 0;
}

public void UpButton() {
    if (isGrounded) {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
}
```

Из-за `transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);` персонаж улетает куда-то как только запускаю игру.

Comment: А чему изначально равна скорость speedX - при старте игры, до первого нажатия на какую-нибудь кнопку?
Если изначально скорость не проинициализирована и задается только при действиях, связанных с нажатием кнопок, то пропробуйте что-то типа такого:
`private void Start() { speedX = 0; }`

Comment: [SerializeField]
 private float speedX = 0.0F; //Скорость игрока

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: тогда оформлю в виде ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если изначально скорость не проинициализирована и задается только при действиях, связанных с нажатием кнопок, то пропробуйте что-то типа такого:

```
private void Start()
{ 
  speedX = 0;
}
```

Comment: Плохой способ, если нужно проинициализировать всего лишь переменную, проще задать ей дефолтное значение, а не переопределять Start().